# Can anyone give me a working DELEGATECALL example?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

I tried many variants of `DELEGATECALL`, but not one of them gave me the desired result.
When used in `assembly: = delegatecall ()`, I also don't get the result.
I also used different versions of Solidity (^ 0.4.13 - ^ 0.5.0). That didn't help either.

Is there a working example of `DELEGATECALL`?
And does `DELEGATECALL` work today?

**

```
contract A{
uint256 public N;

     function C(uint256 _c) public{
         N = _c;
     }
}
```

**

```
contract B{

    function DelCall(address _contractA, uint256 _c) public{
         _contractA.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("C(uint256)")), _c);
         // DELEGATECALL - not works
    }
    function DelCal_B(address _contractA, bytes _b){
         _contractA.delegatecall(_b);
         // DELEGATECALL - not works
    }


    function Call(address _contractA, uint256 _c){
         _contractA.call(bytes4(keccak256("C(uint256)")), _c); 
         // CALL - works
    }
    function Cal_B(address _contractA, bytes _b){
         _contractA.call(_b);
         // CALL - works
    }
}
```